# I´m trying to make a login from a sql database but keep getting this error

Tags: c#, sql

[if you can´t open i will try to explain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QeXRS.png)

basically i get this error 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Table'.'
it tells me that it is in te sda.fill(dtbl) where the error occurs

```
        {
            SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=D:\SQL Database\LOGIN DB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
            string query = "Select * from dbo.Table Where [Username]  = '" + txtUsername.Text.Trim() + "' and [Password] ='" + txtPassword.Text.Trim() + "'";
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(query, sqlcon);
            DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dtbl);
            if (dtbl.Rows.Count == 1)
            {
                EntrarConta entrar = new EntrarConta();
                entrar.Show();
                this.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Check your Username or password");
            }
        }
```

this is the code

Comment: `[dbo].[Table]`? Since `Table` is reserved word

Comment: `Table` is in the list of [Reserved Keywords](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).   You should not use those words in a table- or field-name.

Comment: Please use parameters (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) otherwise you open yourself up to sql injection.

Comment: [Bad habits: Using AttachDBFileName](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-attachdbfilename)

Comment: Reserved words (ANSI SQL-2016, MS SQL Server and others,) can be found at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_reserved_words.

Answer (score 4):

Its because 'Table' is [reserved keyword for T-SQL.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15)

Either **change the table name** or use square bracket around the `[dbo].[Table]`

Comment: it was a mix of that and a dumb thing I did haha, thank you

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `Table` is reserved word and should be *escaped*: `[Table]`.
You can put it like this:

```
    //DONE: wrap IDisposable with using
    using (SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(...)) {
      //DONE: make sql readabale and parametrized  
      string query = 
        @"select 1 
            from [dbo].[Table] 
           where [Username] = @prmUserName
             and [Password] = @prmPassword";

      using (SqlCommand q = new SqlCommand(query, sqlcon)) {
        //TODO: more accurate is to create parameter and then assign the value
        q.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prmUserName", txtUsername.Text.Trim());
        q.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prmPassword", txtPassword.Text.Trim());

        if (q.ExecuteScalar() != null) { // If we've read a record
          EntrarConta entrar = new EntrarConta();
          entrar.Show();

          this.Close(); 
        }
        else {
          MessageBox.Show("Check your Username or password"); 
        }
      }
    }
```

Please, note, that keeping *passwords* in a table is *dangerous* (what if the table is stolen?). Much better to put *hashes* instead of plain text.

Comment: @Charlieface: Thank you! `ExecuteScalar` is indeed more readable